# Why did clearing my Windows 10 memory cache make my game run better?

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card

I recently purchased a new graphics card, and was hoping to see increased performance out of my games. While I did see a huge performance increase, I am still plagued with graphics hitching (intermittent second long pauses in frame updates) that were frustrating me to no end.

Frustrated, I approached the problem like a true professional - I watched a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnKDPLjbg_I&feature=youtu.be) and downloaded some [random program](https://wj32.org/wp/software/empty-standby-list/) that I was instructed to. The point of the program appears to be clearing out the Windows 10 memory cache - (in my case, dropping it from 16GB to ~300MB).

I thought there was no way this would work - certainly the heavy graphics work is done on my dedicated card, and the large textures would be stored there in the VRAM. Not to mention, I still have >20GB of free memory remaining, so I wouldn't think there is a space/paging issue.

Much to my surprise, running the program actually worked. My game ran incredibly smoothly at my desired framerate, with no stuttering or hitching.

Can anyone explain why clearing my memory cache (at least I hope the random program didn't do much else) would have fixed my game's performance issues?

**Before running the program:**

[image]

**After running the program:**

[image]

**No game running (yet memory previously cleaned using program**:

[image]

**Game Running:**

[image]

Comment: Neither screenshot is with the program in question running.  Task Manager does not display information in a helpful way, provide both situations, within RAMMap instead of task manager

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/932994/windows-8-1-cached-memory-and-memory-optimizers

Comment: @Ramhound: Not the same thing. That post talks about memory optimizers, which in any case don't help solve the performance problem caused by standby memory.

Comment: Hey @Ramhound, I added a few RamMap screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good explanation of standby memory is found in the Microsoft article
[Where has all my Physical RAM gone?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Ask-The-Performance-Team/Where-has-all-my-Physical-RAM-gone/ba-p/375315).

In short, this is basically the Windows cache where are kept copies of disk blocks
that were used by processes, in the idea that if these processes are restarted
the required blocks can be found quickly without doing disk reads.

These blocks are not a problem, since they are immediately liberated when a program
requires more memory than exists in free memory.

The gotcha for games is, that if the game wants to allocate as much memory as is
available, for holding the maximum possible of data in memory, it asks Windows
how much memory is free. Windows will return the amount of memory that is free,
but *excluding standby memory*.

The game will then allocate less memory than it could have asked for.
If it would have asked for more memory than the reported amount, this would
have been allocated from the standby memory without a hitch.
The problem is that the game doesn't know how much it could have really
requested.

The program Empty Standby List does something very simple :
It asks for all of memory, reads nothing into it, then frees it.
This way standby memory is in effect cleaned out and all of memory is
now marked as free and available for the game.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but wouldn't I need to run out of free memory to see these type of resource constraints? I added some extra screenshots for context, but it looks like I've got around 10G unallocated just sitting there.

Comment: You should be looking at the sum of Active+Standby+Modified which gives a better measure for what's happening. Before running the game this takes up about one-third of the memory which is mainly Windows in action, but when running the game this goes up to about two-thirds. The game is being nice in not asking for an excessive amount of memory.

Comment: So the game would _prefer_ more memory, but is too polite to ask, even though there's plenty?

Comment: Let's say that the game plans on taking over one-half of free memory. The difference is what is the number from which it takes that half. After running Empty Standby List that number is much larger.

Comment: It seems then like I'm inviting Windows to cache more than it would with less RAM, and then shooting myself in the foot for one of my primary uses, which is games. Great! :)

Comment: Windows does that as an optimization, and it works great for most purposes. You can't use Windows without continuously loading used files into the cache. If running Empty Standby List before running a game is troublesome, you should increase your RAM. Remark that not all games are that naive about Windows and use better API to calculate the free memory than does that game, so it shouldn't be a general problem. Also, most games trust Windows to manage memory and don't pre-allocate that much.