# My computer's memory is at almost 50% with seemingly no processes taking it up, is this normal?

Tags: windows-10

So I've had this laptop for a while and have usually never really payed attention to my memory til now and can't tell if this is normal.

- CPU: AMD Quad Core A6-7310
- Ram: 4GB
- OS: Windows 10 Home
- Memory/Storage:500 GB 5400 rpm Sata

If this is normal or if it gets higher is there a percentage I should worry about it getting to? Picture of my memory usage with no programs running:

[image: Picture of my memory]

Comment: 2GB is the base minimum for running Windows 10, and I have a laptop that similarly uses around 2GB on a clean boot. So, anecdotally, yes, but hopefully someone will post a more authoritative answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did clearing my Windows 10 memory cache make my game run better?](https://superuser.com/questions/1369696/why-did-clearing-my-windows-10-memory-cache-make-my-game-run-better) and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's normal.

Part of it is that applications ARE using that data. As you can see from your screenshot, just the applications showing there at the top of the Task Manager list total nearly 25%.

And part of it is that Windows uses the memory your computer has to make the computer run better. Unused memory is wasted memory, so the default behavior of the OS these days is to use the memory available to it. If applications require memory, Windows can shift the load around to give them the resources they required, but if nothing else is using your RAM, Windows will happily make use of it.

Comment: Looking at the Task Manager display, there are some things I would not want running in my system such as Cortana and a non-antivirus anti-malware product, and that is just the stuff that is visible.  Firefox alone when running easily gobbles up 1 GB or more.  Judiciously pruning unwanted applications and services will help the system run in 4 GB, but -- memory is cheap! -- stick in another 4GB or 8GB.  Memory usage will look better and Windows can use the extra memory for disk cache when an application is not using it.

Comment: The root of the issue though is that Windows will use more memory if more memory is available.