# RAM Issue. Desktop Windows Manager is using a lot of RAM? Can I reduce it? Is it a bug?

Tags: memory, cache, dwm

[image: Image 1]

I wanted to free up cached and temporary files on my computer for more RAM space for 3D work. After clearing most of my cached files I realised that there was still a lot of RAM being used, even though only 2 chrome tabs were open.

[image: Image 2]

After checking Task Manager, and doing some research on DWM, it seemed that DWM was using more RAM than expected/needed.

Was wondering if there was a way to reduce the RAM taken up by this operation.

Notes: I am using 2 monitors, although after unplugging one there was no change in RAM usage of DWM.

Comment: 8 GB is the minimum for Windows to work comfortably nowadays. Could you add *another* 8 GB of RAM to the computer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did clearing my Windows 10 memory cache make my game run better?](https://superuser.com/questions/1369696/why-did-clearing-my-windows-10-memory-cache-make-my-game-run-better) There is no RAM problem with your computer. Everything is normal and you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score -2):

Try updating your driver of Display and Processor. It can be driver issue. Go to Start -> settings -> Windows Update. It can also be a malware issue: Run a scan using antivirus, reboot the pc

**Thanks**

Please comment for it worked or not

Comment: Driver for what??

Comment: Oh, Sorry i forgot to include: Display and Processor of course

Comment: Please see the edited post